# Reopening a connection using ORMLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, ormlite

My situation is this. I have an OrmLiteBaseActivity where there is my main menu. When I press a button I go in "backup mode" and I want to download a backup sqlite db from my website.
The problem is that when I try to upload the file, I get no error but the db is not updated untill I close and reopen the software. I would like the update to be on-the-fly.

I've tried on my OrmLiteBaseActivity something like this:

```
case BACKUP_ID:
    getHelper().close();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Backup.class);
    this.startActivity(i);
    return true;
```

The I go to the backup activity, update the file, then I want to go back but I got this error:

```
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229): Getting connectionSource called after closed
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229): java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getConnectionSource(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:78)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:171)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at info.dierrelabs.h4m.ormliteinterface.DatabaseHelper.getPlayerDao(DatabaseHelper.java:159)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at info.dierrelabs.h4m.team.TeamList.onCreate(TeamList.java:20)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-15 19:27:45.359: ERROR/DatabaseHelper(229):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there something I'm missing? I assumed that using an OrmLiteBaseActivity would reopen the db everytime I open a new OrmLiteBaseActivity. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the entire exception @dierre?  It's hard to see who is giving that "error".

Comment: Yes of course. Tonight I'll do it. Could you tell me if there is a way to copy/paste from logcat?

Comment: I just use `adb logcat` from the command line in a terminal window.  You should be able to get it out of Eclipse's window as well.

Comment: edited with the complete error.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer @dierre?

Comment: @Gray: Hi! No, actually I solved it in another way. I forgot to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved it. When the user presses the backup button, here's what's happening:

```
case BACKUP_ID:
    getHelper().close();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Backup.class);
    this.startActivity(i);
    return true;
```

then I need to reopen this connection. You can actually do it like this (after I swapped sqlite files):

```
            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(Backup.this);
            db.getWritableDatabase();
```

The class `Backup` just extends `Activity`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not doing something wrong but you are doing something atypical.

In `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getConnectionSource()`, it logs an error because someone is trying to get a connection source after `close()` has been called:

```
public ConnectionSource getConnectionSource() {
    if (!isOpen) {
        // we don't throw this exception, but log it for debugging purposes
        logger.error(new IllegalStateException(), 
                    "Getting connectionSource called after closed");
    }
    return connectionSource;
}
```

You can override this method in your helper to *not* throw a message:

```
private ConnectionSource connectionSource = null;
@Override
public ConnectionSource getConnectionSource() {
    if (connectionSource == null) {
        connectionSource = super.getConnectionSource();
    }
    return connectionSource;
}
```

That will fix the error log message but the question is whether the copy and the new database work.  You might want to take a look at the two database code example.  It maintains it's own database counters and the like which you may have to do:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/android-hello-two-dbs

Comment: sir, its really nice the way you explain things here, but why isnt the same documented on the site? there are some errors that come and might be no ones faced :(

Comment: I'm not sure this is a common enough occurrence @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille that it bears calling out in the docs.

Comment: yes true it is, but just to probably put it all in one place :) may be.. (but may be just cz its not common, its needed somewhere, saves time esp when its not known how to search for the error since sqliteDatabaseHelper and OrmliteHelper both may be pointing to the same error, but native helper supercedes and the bug is left unsolved at the end of the day, with a fresh search next day)

Comment: but again this is just my point of view :).. thanks for the answers you've posted in most of the ormlite errors. they've really helped me alot. and iv noted them in one file just incase i face them again. :).. God bless